# Javascript Object SVG align tooltip to the text

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip

After read the svg structure i try to create custom tooltip but i can't align to the text tags, if the page it is empty it is ok, but when it is some other component inside HTML page   the tooltip it is not align.

Below you can find a code and svg file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
      .tooltip-svg {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>



    <div class="container">
      <h1>ATAC - TRANSLATOR</h1>
      
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="test-tabs.html">Test Tabs</a></li>
          <li><a href="wipo-lex.html">WipoLex</a></li>
          <li><a href="jp199.html">JP199</a></li>
          <li><a href="test-list.html">test-list</a></li>
          <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="test2.html">test2</a></li>
          <li><a href="test3.html">test3</a></li>
          <li><a href="test4.html">test4</a></li>
          <li><a href="test5.html">test5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown-list-language"></div>


      <div class="ps-panel--content font-size--small"><b>Note:</b> Text based on automatic Optical Character Recognition processes. Please use the PDF version for legal matters
        <p></p><span id="detailMainForm:MyTabViewId:descriptionPanel" class="js-claims-panel needTranslation-description" lang="en">
           <div><span class="patent-claims-language--displayed ">[EN ]</span><img id="detailMainForm:MyTabViewId:j_idt3087:0:j_idt3091" width="5px" alt="" >
           </div>
           <div class="searchhit content--text-wrap claims-description claims-description_en">
   
    
            <div class="par">
              653,629; 1,636,190; 3,202,447; 3,332,045; 3,977,436;3,979,068;
            </div>
            <div class="par">
              4,090,668; 4,106,508; 4,159,026; 4,253,493; 4,295,111;4,306,589;
            </div>
            <div class="par">
              4,403,756; 4,489,863; 4,561,632; 4,534,539; 4,524,797;4,574,841;
            </div>
            <div class="par">
              4,690,371; 4,877,186; 5,012,977; 5,118,040; 5,280,806;5,254,083;
            </div>
            

            <object id="svgObject" class="atac-svg-tranlator" data="A07.svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="800" height="1100"></object>

            
                </div></span>
              </div>

              <div id="tooltipSvg" class="tooltip-svg">
                This is a custom tooltip
              </div>
                  
    </div>
     
    <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const svgObject = document.getElementById('svgObject');
  const tooltipElement = document.getElementById('tooltipSvg');

  svgObject.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;

    if (svgDoc) {
      const textElements = svgDoc.querySelectorAll('text');

      textElements.forEach(textElement => {
        textElement.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
          const svgRect = svgObject.getBoundingClientRect();
          const textRect = textElement.getBoundingClientRect();

          const mouseX = event.clientX - svgRect.left;
          const mouseY = event.clientY - svgRect.top;

          // Position the tooltip relative to the text element
          tooltipElement.style.display = 'block';
          tooltipElement.style.left = mouseX + 'px';
          tooltipElement.style.top = mouseY - 20 + 'px'; // Adjust this value as needed
        });

        textElement.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
          tooltipElement.style.display = 'none';
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log('SVG document not loaded');
    }
  });
});

    </script>
    

   
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the svg file, need to be embedded with object tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- This is a Stata 15.0 generated SVG file (http://www.stata.com) -->

<svg version="1.1" width="6.30in" height="2.40in" viewBox="0 0 4536 1728" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <desc>Stata Graph - Graph</desc>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="4536" height="1728" style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:none"/>
    <rect x="0.00" y="0.00" width="4535.86" height="1728.00" style="fill:#FFFFFF"/>
    <rect x="1.73" y="1.73" width="4532.40" height="1724.54" style="fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:3.46"/>
    <rect x="350.55" y="343.47" width="123.46" height="665.26" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="352.05" y="344.97" width="120.46" height="662.26" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="556.65" y="524.78" width="123.46" height="483.95" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="558.15" y="526.28" width="120.46" height="480.95" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="762.76" y="616.92" width="123.46" height="391.81" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="764.26" y="618.42" width="120.46" height="388.81" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="969.00" y="773.28" width="123.32" height="235.46" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="970.50" y="774.78" width="120.32" height="232.46" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="1175.11" y="779.23" width="123.32" height="229.50" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="1176.61" y="780.73" width="120.32" height="226.50" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="1381.21" y="786.46" width="123.32" height="222.27" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="1382.71" y="787.96" width="120.32" height="219.27" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="1587.32" y="826.01" width="123.32" height="182.72" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="1588.82" y="827.51" width="120.32" height="179.72" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="1793.42" y="849.40" width="123.32" height="159.33" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="1794.92" y="850.90" width="120.32" height="156.33" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="1999.53" y="871.23" width="123.46" height="137.50" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="2001.03" y="872.73" width="120.46" height="134.50" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="2205.63" y="875.62" width="123.46" height="133.11" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="2207.13" y="877.12" width="120.46" height="130.11" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="2411.73" y="884.41" width="123.46" height="124.32" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="2413.23" y="885.91" width="120.46" height="121.32" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="2617.84" y="904.97" width="123.46" height="103.77" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="2619.34" y="906.47" width="120.46" height="100.77" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="2823.94" y="912.20" width="123.46" height="96.54" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="2825.44" y="913.70" width="120.46" height="93.54" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="3030.05" y="913.76" width="123.46" height="94.98" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="3031.55" y="915.26" width="120.46" height="91.98" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="3236.15" y="920.99" width="123.46" height="87.75" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="3237.65" y="922.49" width="120.46" height="84.75" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="3442.26" y="944.38" width="123.46" height="64.36" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="3443.76" y="945.88" width="120.46" height="61.36" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="3648.36" y="963.37" width="123.46" height="45.36" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="3649.86" y="964.87" width="120.46" height="42.36" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="3854.47" y="975.14" width="123.46" height="33.60" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="3855.97" y="976.64" width="120.46" height="30.60" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="4060.71" y="998.53" width="123.32" height="10.21" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="4062.21" y="1000.03" width="120.32" height="7.21" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <rect x="4266.82" y="999.94" width="123.32" height="8.79" style="fill:#2E62AC"/>
    <rect x="4268.32" y="1001.44" width="120.32" height="5.79" style="fill:none;stroke:#2E62AC;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <text x="4025.56" y="119.83" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">ANNUAL GROWTH RATE (%)</text>
    <text x="415.89" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">27.1</text>
    <text x="621.72" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">13.4</text>
    <text x="827.68" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–31.5</text>
    <text x="1033.50" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–11.0</text>
    <text x="1239.32" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">1.3</text>
    <text x="1445.28" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–12.6</text>
    <text x="1651.10" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">92.3</text>
    <text x="1857.07" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–6.8</text>
    <text x="2062.89" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–22.3</text>
    <text x="2268.71" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–9.0</text>
    <text x="2474.67" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–26.1</text>
    <text x="2680.49" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–4.1</text>
    <text x="2886.46" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">26.9</text>
    <text x="3092.28" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–32.3</text>
    <text x="3298.24" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–15.5</text>
    <text x="3504.06" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–17.0</text>
    <text x="3709.88" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–26.2</text>
    <text x="3915.84" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">0.0</text>
    <text x="4121.66" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">..</text>
    <text x="4327.63" y="199.92" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">–25.0</text>
    <text x="415.89" y="308.85" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">455</text>
    <text x="621.72" y="490.16" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">331</text>
    <text x="827.68" y="582.30" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">268</text>
    <text x="1033.50" y="738.65" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">161</text>
    <text x="1239.32" y="744.46" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">157</text>
    <text x="1445.28" y="751.84" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">152</text>
    <text x="1651.10" y="791.39" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">125</text>
    <text x="1857.07" y="814.78" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">109</text>
    <text x="2062.89" y="836.61" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">94</text>
    <text x="2268.71" y="841.00" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">91</text>
    <text x="2474.67" y="849.79" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">85</text>
    <text x="2680.49" y="870.20" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">71</text>
    <text x="2886.46" y="877.57" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">66</text>
    <text x="3092.28" y="878.99" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">65</text>
    <text x="3298.24" y="886.36" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">60</text>
    <text x="3504.06" y="909.75" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">44</text>
    <text x="3709.88" y="928.75" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">31</text>
    <text x="3915.84" y="940.51" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">23</text>
    <text x="4121.66" y="963.90" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">7</text>
    <text x="4327.63" y="965.32" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:55.28px;fill:#2E62ac" text-anchor="middle">6</text>
    <line x1="415.89" y1="247.93" x2="415.89" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="621.72" y1="429.24" x2="621.72" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="827.68" y1="521.38" x2="827.68" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="1033.50" y1="677.87" x2="1033.50" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="1239.32" y1="683.69" x2="1239.32" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="1445.28" y1="690.92" x2="1445.28" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="1651.10" y1="730.47" x2="1651.10" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="1857.07" y1="753.86" x2="1857.07" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="2062.89" y1="775.83" x2="2062.89" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="2268.71" y1="780.22" x2="2268.71" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="2474.67" y1="788.87" x2="2474.67" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="2680.49" y1="809.42" x2="2680.49" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="2886.46" y1="816.65" x2="2886.46" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="3092.28" y1="818.21" x2="3092.28" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="3298.24" y1="825.44" x2="3298.24" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="3504.06" y1="848.83" x2="3504.06" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="3709.88" y1="867.83" x2="3709.88" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="3915.84" y1="879.59" x2="3915.84" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="4121.66" y1="902.98" x2="4121.66" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <line x1="4327.63" y1="904.40" x2="4327.63" y2="220.29" style="stroke:#D0D0D0;stroke-width:3.00"/>
    <text x="179.13" y="621.03" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:66.06px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-90 179.13,621.03)" text-anchor="middle">Madrid applications</text>
    <text x="427.22" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 427.22,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">India</text>
    <text x="633.32" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 633.32,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Bulgaria</text>
    <text x="839.42" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 839.42,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Ukraine</text>
    <text x="1045.53" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 1045.53,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Brazil</text>
    <text x="1251.63" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 1251.63,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Viet Nam</text>
    <text x="1457.74" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 1457.74,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Malaysia</text>
    <text x="1663.84" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 1663.84,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Colombia</text>
    <text x="1869.95" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 1869.95,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Kazakhstan</text>
    <text x="2076.05" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 2076.05,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Indonesia</text>
    <text x="2282.16" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 2282.16,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Morocco</text>
    <text x="2488.26" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 2488.26,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Mexico</text>
    <text x="2694.36" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 2694.36,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Republic of Moldova</text>
    <text x="2900.47" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 2900.47,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Egypt</text>
    <text x="3106.72" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 3106.72,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Thailand</text>
    <text x="3312.82" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 3312.82,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Philippines</text>
    <text x="3518.92" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 3518.92,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Iran (Islamic Republic of)</text>
    <text x="3725.03" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 3725.03,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Armenia</text>
    <text x="3931.13" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 3931.13,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Georgia</text>
    <text x="4137.24" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 4137.24,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Pakistan</text>
    <text x="4343.34" y="1058.19" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:59.96px;fill:#000000" transform="rotate(-45 4343.34,1058.19)" text-anchor="end">Algeria</text>
    <text x="2370.34" y="1636.30" style="font-family:'Noto Sans';font-size:69.17px;fill:#000000" text-anchor="middle">Origin</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.